# Why does my pyrogram bot keep turning off?

Tags: python, pyrogram

For some reason my bot always turns off without printing any output to the command line or showing any kind of error. The bot functions properly for a few hours after being turned on. Basic code looks like this:

```
app = Client("my_account", '123456', '123456789abcd')
TESTING = "321"
USER_ID = "123"

chat_mapping = {TESTING: "-10011111111111", USER_ID: "-10011111111111"}


@app.on_message()
def my_handler(client, message):
    if str(message.chat.id) not in chat_mapping:
        return
    elif str(message.chat.id) == USER_ID:
        storeMsg(message)
    else:
        print(message.text)

app.run()
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try making a logging file that takes logs when you wrap the `my_handler` function in a try except. You may find that it is failing because of a bad call which would be logged in permanently stored logs. It should log when a success takes place and when a failure takes place.

Comment: If that's the entirety of your code, you're comparing `str(message.chat.id)` with `USER_ID` which is undefined.

Comment: @James Thanks, I will do that. Is there any way you know of to automatically restart app.run() should it stop working? I have tried running it in a while loop but again, it randomly stops and doesn't restart - maybe it is being hung up on something?

Answer (score 0):

`if str(message.chat.id) not in chat_mapping`
in this lane, your statement will check if `message.chat.id` is equal one of the keys of dictionary, not values.

Means your `message.chat.id` can't be 123 or 321.

```
USER_ID = some id
chat_mapping = [some ids] 
@app.on_message()
def my_handler(client, message):
    if str(message.chat.id) not in chat_mapping:
        return
    elif str(message.chat.id) == USER_ID:
        storeMsg(message)
    else:
        print(message.text)

app.run()
```